# Lazy list wrapped in IO

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, io-monad

Suppose the code

```
f :: IO [Int]
f = f >>= return . (0 :)

g :: IO [Int]
g = f >>= return . take 3
```

When I run `g` in ghci, it cause stackoverflow. But I was thinking maybe it could be evaluated lazily and produce `[0, 0, 0]` wrapped in `IO`. I suspect `IO` is to blame here, but I really have no idea. Obviously the following works:

```
f' :: [Int]
f' = 0 : f'

g' :: [Int]
g' = take 3 f'
```

---

**Edit:** In fact I am not interested in having such a simple function `f`, original code looked more along the lines:

```
h :: a -> IO [Either b c]
h a = do
    (r, a') <- h' a
    case r of
        x@(Left  _) -> h a' >>= return . (x :)
        y@(Right _) -> return [y]

h' :: IO (Either b c, a)
-- something non trivial

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ print . take 3 =<< h a
```

`h` does some `IO` computations and stores invalid (`Left`) responses in a list until a valid response (`Right`) is produced. The attempt is to construct the list lazily even though we are in the `IO` monad. So that someone reading the result of `h` can start consuming the list even before it is complete (because it may even be infinite). And if the one reading the results cares only for the first `3` entries no matter what, the rest of the list does not even have to be constructed. And I am getting the feeling that this will not be possible :/.

Comment: Does `h'` call `h`? Can you actually show us the real code? Do you want it to only perform enough `IO` to produce the demanded results, or should it perform it all regardless?

Comment: only to produce the demanded results, and the actual code is a lot lot bigger and messier, I still believe I am helping it when I paste simplified versions. `h` is not called from `h'`

Comment: I am making mistakes, I should sleep on this.

Comment: Ah, well, if you want evaluation to drive execution, `unsafeInterleaveIO` is your only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate usage, but `unsafeInterleaveIO` would get you the behavior you're asking for, by deferring the IO actions of `f` until the value inside of `f` is asked for:

```
module Tmp where
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafeInterleaveIO)

f :: IO [Int]
f = unsafeInterleaveIO f >>= return . (0 :)

g :: IO [Int]
g = f >>= return . take 3

*Tmp> g
[0,0,0]
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick, thank you. Are there any drawbacks to using this, the name is not very reassuring ;).

Comment: Well, that's why I said I'm not sure it's appropriate. unsafeInterleaveIO is okay sometimes, but is dangerous in general; find someone more experienced than I am to tell you whether this is a good idea.

Comment: @JakubDaniel The drawback is that it will screw up your intuition about how `IO` happens: normally, in `m >>= f`, we expect the `IO` of `m` to  happen before `f` is applied to an argument; but in `unsafeInterleaveIO m >>= f` the `IO` of `m` will be delayed. Translating this to your question context, this means the consumer of `h`'s list decides which (if any!) iterations of `h'` get performed. It's also fragile to compiler optimizations. So if you're doing something where you actually care about the `IO` that happens -- which is almost always -- it's a pretty bad idea!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `IO` is to blame here. `>>=` for `IO` is strict in the "state of the world". If you write `m >>= h`, you'll get an action that first performs the action `m`, then applies `h` to the result, and finally performs the action `h` yields. It doesn't matter that your `f` action doesn't "do anything"; it has to be performed anyway. Thus you end up in an infinite loop starting the `f` action over and over.

Thankfully, there is a way around this, because `IO` is an instance of `MonadFix`. You can "magically" access the result of an `IO` action from within that action. Critically, that access must be sufficiently lazy, or you'll throw yourself into an infinite loop.

```
import Control.Monad.Fix
import Data.Functor ((<$>))

f :: IO [Int]
f = mfix (\xs -> return (0 : xs))

-- This `g` is just like yours, but prettier IMO
g :: IO [Int]
g = take 3 <$> f
```

There's even a bit of syntactic sugar in GHC for this letting you use `do` notation with the `rec` keyword or `mdo` notation.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}

f' :: IO [Int]
f' = do
  rec res <- (0:) <$> (return res :: IO [Int])
  return res

f'' :: IO [Int]
f'' = mdo
  res <- f'
  return (0 : res)
```

For more interesting examples of ways to use `MonadFix`, see the [Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/MonadFix).

Comment: I maybe oversimplified thinks, I will edit the original post.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a monad that mixes the capabilities of lists and `IO`. Luckily, that's just what [`ListT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-t-0.4.5.1/docs/ListT.html) is for. Here's your example in that form, with an `h'` that computes the Collatz sequence and asks the user how they feel about each element in the sequence (I couldn't really think of anything convincing that fit the shape of your outline).

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import qualified ListT as L

h :: Int -> L.ListT IO (Either String ())
h a = do
  (r, a') <- liftIO (h' a)
  case r of
    x@(Left  _) -> L.cons x (h a')
    y@(Right _) -> return y

h' :: Int -> IO (Either String (), Int)
h' 1 = return (Right (), 1)
h' n = do
  putStrLn $ "Say something about " ++ show n
  s <- getLine
  return (Left s, if even n then n `div` 2 else 3*n + 1)

main = readLn >>= L.traverse_ print . L.take 3 . h
```

Here's how it looks in ghci:

```
> main
2
Say something about 2
small
Left "small"
Right ()
> main
3
Say something about 3
prime
Left "prime"
Say something about 10
not prime
Left "not prime"
Say something about 5
fiver
Left "fiver"
```

I suppose modern approaches would use pipes or conduits or iteratees or something, but I don't know enough about them to talk about the tradeoffs compared to `ListT`.

Comment: This seems like a pretty simple approach, but that library is a bit obnoxious--why doesn't it export the `ListT` constructor?

Comment: Is it likely that one day this `ListT` replaces the one in `transformers` ?

Comment: Can I anyhow transform lazily the `ListT IO (Either a b)` into `IO [Either a b]` so that I don't have to polute the callers with ListT things? I would have expected `toList` to be lazy but it seems not to be :/ I also wish to pick whether to use `take 3` or just identity, so I expected the stream to be potentially infinite.

Comment: @JakubDaniel You may of course substitute `id` for `take 3` in the above definition of `main`, no problem. It is true that `toList` is not lazy in the sense of lazy IO -- which you should treat as a good thing for all the reasons I outlined on the other answer. You will need to decide whether you want to call `take 3` or `id` before calling `toList`. However, `toList` is indeed the correct way to turn a `ListT IO (Either a b)` into an `IO [Either a b]`.

Comment: Yes but if i choose `id` then when the function does not terminate, the strictness causes that I cannot read the intermediate results :( which beats the purpose of using `ListT` instead of normal list as in my edit to the original question. It is often the case, that the function does not terminate.

Comment: @JakubDaniel This is not correct: as my example shows, you can use `traverse_` to inspect intermediate values as they are available.

Comment: I mean, you cannot do that lazily over the standard list, which I see as really a negative fact. As I said earlier, I was hoping for a solution that would produce `IO [Either a b]` which I could inspect lazily. The only way to get `IO [...]` from `ListT` seems to be `toList` which however is not lazy, so once you do that, you lose laziness. If you use `traverse_` you cannot keep constructing the lazy list `[...]`.

Comment: So if your on-demand expansion of the list is very far (meaning over many calls to other `IO` actions) then you need to polute the whole stack with `ListT`, which prohibits you from concealing the implementation :/

Comment: @JakubDaniel, it's not really pollution, I don't think, so much as expressing the fact that values are consumed as they are produced. Hiding the fact that producing the items is effectful doesn't necessarily seem to be a good thing.

Comment: I did not mean to be hiding the effect rather than hidding the source of laziness (`ListT`). Enlarging the stack of monads with another transformer seems to me as pollution.